# Mongod authentication makes GCP VM Unreachable

Tags: mongodb, authentication, google-cloud-platform

I'm using GCP VM to run a MongoDB instance.

It works very well, with authentication turned off, but once I turned it on "enabled" by editing
`sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf`, and then restart service using `sudo service mongod restart`.

Once I did this, and try to connect to my DB using my credentials, I've got the following error from mongo:

`mongo mongodb://<gcp vm statcic ip>:<mongodb static port>`

result in:

```
connecting to: mongodb://<myservererIP>:<mongodbport>
2020-04-04T19:30:36.644+0200 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server
 <myservererIP>:<mongodbport>, connection attempt failed: SocketException:
 Error connecting to <myservererIP>:<mongodbport> :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

My VM IP is Static and account in mongo were created according to mongoDB document, they should be fine, even if they were not, I suppose that I should have an "Authorization required" or something, and not connection refused or Network Unreachable.

Comment: "connection refused" implies that nothing is listening on that port, is the mongod running? Might check the mongod log for details.

Comment: @Joe Mongod instance is running on remote server.

Comment: The error still means that something other than an application actively refused the connection.  Check for firewalls or DNS issues, check with netstat or ss that the mongod is listening on the port you expect, and try to telnet/nc from the local server to that port.

Comment: Thanks for you help @joe I've figured out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually found the problem.

In `/etc/mongod.conf` , I thought that `#security:` was here for informative purpose , for file structuring, but you actually have to also uncomment it, along with `authentication: enable`.

Otherwise, mongod will detect the `mongod.conf` file as corrupted/bad format, and run without it (probably using a default conf).

I went from:

```
#security:
    authorization: enabled
```

to

```
security:
   authorization: enabled
```

Probably a very poor mistake from a begginer, but I'll keep it here, maybe it will help someone.